# android maven generating apk and jar file separately

Tags: android, maven

When I try to run mvn clean install, it is generating two separate .jar files containing classes and .apk containing resource files.
I don't think so this is issue with pom file as my pom file is same as maven tutorial mentioned.
any pointers on what might be the issue?

Comment: This is how Android SDK suppose to work, it compiles java code first, then convert .class files to Dalvik-compatible .dex (Dalvik Executable) files, nothing to do with android-maven-plugin.

Comment: @yorkw, right now it is generating apk file with no class files in it. I don't think so this is correct because when we generate apk file from eclipse we have apk which has class files included it doesnt have separate jar file even for main project.

Answer (score 0):

Resolving this issue as issue was related to systempath tag for jar files. Maven 3.6.0 was giving error for local files instead of this added jars to repository.
Thanks Yorkw for the help